# Update ModelState in ASP MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, modelstate

I'm completely new to ASP MVC, so sorry if I'm asking something stupid.

The ModelState won't get validated. It says `venue.VenueType.Type` is null. Am I doing this right?
I'm already giving a value to `Type` in the controller (don't know if this is best practice), but the ModelState doesn't recognise this.

I've read about using `TryUpdateModel`. This didn't lead to any succes, although I'm not sure I was using it right.

Should I use a ViewModel for this? Which fields do I use in that?

These are the two models:

```
public class Venue
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual VenueType VenueType { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<VisitInfo> VisitInfos { get; set; }
}

public class VenueType
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

A create action for the Venue class:

```
    //
    // GET: /Venue/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.venueTypes = new SelectList(context.VenueTypes, "Id", "Type");
        return View();
    } 

    //
    // POST: /Venue/Create

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Venue venue)
    {
        venue.VenueType = context.VenueTypes.Find(venue.VenueType.Id);

        ViewBag.venueTypes = new SelectList(context.VenueTypes, "Id", "Type");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            context.Venues.Add(venue);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
        return View(venue);
    }
```

And a create view:

```
@model eBouncer_Web.Models.Venue

@* This partial view defines form fields that will appear when creating and editing entities *@
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.VenueType)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.VenueType.Id, (SelectList) ViewBag.venueTypes)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write your own validations you don't need `ModelState`.

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Venue venue)
    {
        venue.VenueType = context.VenueTypes.Find(venue.VenueType.Id);

        ViewBag.venueTypes = new SelectList(context.VenueTypes, "Id", "Type");

        if (Venue != null && Venue.Name != null)//etc.. or other validations get here...
        {
            context.Venues.Add(venue);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }
        return View(venue);
    }
```

Comment: So, it's not best practice to always use `ModelState`?

Comment: I can not say that best or worst.. But model is yours, so you can manage all validations yourself to my mind..